# Python While loop that accepts only integer

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have this loop and I am having difficulty making it to accept online integer. No string.

```
def addItem(menu, order):
    # get item no from user
    itemNo = int(input('your choice : '))
    # validate item no
    if itemNo == -1:
        return itemNo
    while itemNo not in range(1, len(menu) + 1):
        itemNo = int(input('Invalid input, try again: '))
        if itemNo == -1:
            return itemNo
```

Comment: What is an *online integer* ? Could you post the full code ?

Comment: do you mean to enforce the input here: ***itemNo = int(input('Invalid input, try again: '))*** to take integer types only?

Comment: Have you tried putting `itemNo = int(input('Invalid input, try again: '))` in a `try .. except` block, catching the exception you get when anything but a valid integer is entered?

Comment: That was a typo ...I meant to say Only integer

Answer (score 0):

You can throw in a try/catch in a function that does it

```
def get_input():
    not_valid = True
    while not_valid:
        itemNo = input("your choice: ")
        try:
           itemNo = int(itemNo) #Try convert the input to an integer
           return itemNo
        except TypeError: #That fails - start over
            print("Enter only integers!")
```

and use that

```py
def addItem(menu, order):
    # get item no from user
    itemNo = get_input()
    # validate item no
    if itemNo == -1:
        return itemNo
    while itemNo not in range(1, len(menu) + 1):
        itemNo = int(input('Invalid input, try again: '))
        if itemNo == -1:
            return itemNo
```